# Unity 2017.4.1f Networking how do you handle multiple AudioListeners

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

What's the best way to manage AudioListeners in Unity when networking?

I understand that I only need one active AudioListener per client...

I've tried disabling the player prefab AudioListener component, and re-enabling it via code in the OnStartLocalPlayer() function (but this hasn't worked)

I've tried disabling all other AudioListeners via code on Start() but this doesn't account for clients that join afterwards.

Comment: Add it on start if they are the local player? `if(isLocalPlayer) this.gameObject.addComponent<AudioListener>();`

Comment: Post your code and we will tell you why it is not working. Also put it on Start() instead of OnStartLocalPlayer(), and make sure OnStartLocalPlayer()  is the overhead function that activates the entire object, etc.